# Retain AppTheme change using a switch

Tags: android

I have a class file that changes the apps theme on the click of a button, and is supposed to change the theme when the MainActivity starts to keep the theme selected.

But the theme resets to the default light theme (not supposed to) after restarting the app with the dark theme applied, there are dark and light theme options.

Could someone look at my code or just suggest something, any help is appreciated.

```
    public class themeUtils  {
    private static int cTheme;
    public final static int DARK = 1;
    public final static int LIGHT = 0;

    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
    {
        cTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }

    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
    {
        switch (cTheme)
        {
            default:
            case LIGHT:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
                break;
            case DARK:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Dark);
                break;
        }
    } 
}
```

And the line on `MainActivity` startup that is supposed to retain the previously selected theme.

```
themeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
```

Buttons to set theme

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    return builder
            .setTitle("Theme")
            .setNegativeButton("Dark", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    themeUtils.changeToTheme(getActivity(), themeUtils.DARK);
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Light", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    themeUtils.changeToTheme(getActivity(), themeUtils.LIGHT);
                }
            })
            .create();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can store which theme is active in sharedPreference and apply it in onCreate

Comment: Figured out how to do so, thanks for your help @Berkay92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used a sharedPreference for saving the theme.